# How to use data first in renderPartial in yii1.1

Tags: php, yii

From action I am rendering a view and passing data to view

```
public function actionSome(){
//code
$this->render('someView', 'model'=>$model);
```

}

Now in view i am calling renderPartial and passing the model variable in that
I want that the data that was sent to view should be first utilized by view of renderPartial and the by the view that was rendered by action. How to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please, more detailed

Comment: your question is not clear , post more details

Comment: i want to pass the variable to both render and renderPartial from controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the model variable available in the partial view too? If so, use the same syntax for renderPartial as you've used for render - add an array of key / variable pairs:

someView.php:

```
$this->renderPartial('somePartial', array('model' => $model));
```

Comment: i want to pass the variable to both render and renderPartial from controller. Dont want to pass the variable from view to renderPartial